# update missing values in dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have dataframe with missing values. i need to update missing values in two ways.
1. from same dataframe based on latest date and id.
2. from another dataframe based on date and id

```
df
id  date        name    location    type
11  08-05-2019  aim     ind         ss
12  08-05-2019  paul    uk          ee
11  08-04-2019  aim     ee
13  08-05-2019  tera    uk          jj
13  08-01-2019  tera                kk
15  08-09-2019          usa         ii
15  08-05-2019          uk          ii
13  08-05-2019  tera    uk
```

expected output based on filling the nan's from same dataframe based on id and latest date

```
df1
id  date        name    location    type
11  08-05-2019  aim     ind         ss
12  08-05-2019  paul    uk          ee
11  08-04-2019  aim     ind         ss
13  08-05-2019  tera    uk          jj
13  08-01-2019  tera    uk          kk
15  08-09-2019          usa         ii
15  08-05-2019          uk          ii
13  08-05-2019  tera    uk          jj
```

In df1, i need to replace only nan's values from dataframe y based on date and id column.

```
y
id  date        name    location    type    rev
11  08-05-2019  aim     ind         ss      yes
12  08-05-2019  paul    uk          ee      no
11  08-04-2019  aim     ind         ee      yes
13  08-05-2019  tera    uk          jj      yes
13  08-01-2019  tera    uk          kk      yes
15  08-09-2019  sam     usa         ii      no
15  08-05-2019  jim     uk          ii      no
13  08-05-2019  tera    uk          kk      no
14  09-05-2019  tiya    uk          kk      yes
15  10-05-2019  tiya    ind         kk      yes
```

I tried this code for 2nd option but didn't work exactly.

```
y.set_index(['id','date']).combine_first(df1.set_index(['id','date'])).reset_index()
```

and

```
df, y = df.set_index('id','date'), y.set_index('id','date')
df.update(y)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

but getting multi- index error

I was not able to get df1 from df so directly tried to update df with help of y

final expected output is

```
id  date        name    location    type
11  08-05-2019  aim     ind         ss
12  08-05-2019  paul    uk          ee
11  08-04-2019  aim     ind         ee
13  08-05-2019  tera    uk          jj
13  08-01-2019  tera    uk          kk
15  08-09-2019  sam     usa         ii
15  08-05-2019  jim     uk          ii
13  08-05-2019  tera    uk          kk
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just got the dataframe names in reverse order. The following should work

```
df1.set_index(['id','date']).combine_first(y[df1.columns].set_index(['id','date'])).reset_index()
```

Comment: This is adding extra rows to df1. i need to replace only the nan values in df1 without changing df1.shape

Comment: instead of y try y.drop('rev',axis=1) in the code or pass specific columns like y[df1.columns]